# Garbled code when using URLSubmit[] to request CJK web page

Tags: character-encoding, webtools

When importing content containing Chinese ([CJK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_characters)) characters, correct results can be obtained by using `URLread`

```mathematica
URLRead["https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/35359905", "Body"]
```

[image: screenshot of correct output]

But when using `URLSubmit`, the output is garbled

```mathematica
URLSubmit[
 HTTPRequest["https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/35359905", 
  CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"], 
 HandlerFunctions -> <|"BodyReceived" -> ((body = #Body) &)|>]
```

[image: screenshot: output contains weird characters]

Comment: It seems that the notion of "Body" is not consistent across different functions. URLRead's Body is already decoded with respect to response's headers, here `ContentType->text/html; charset=utf-8`. For `URLSubmit` is is raw string, so either use Jean-Pierre's answer or `FromCharacterCode[ToCharacterCode@#Body, "UTF8"]`.

Comment: @Kuba I can't run your code well [![jJCDIJ.png](https://s1.ax1x.com/2022/07/04/jJCDIJ.png)](https://imgtu.com/i/jJCDIJ)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that using `BodyByteArray` is the preferred approach.

```
URLSubmit[
 HTTPRequest["https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/35359905", 
  CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"], 
 HandlerFunctions -> <|
   "BodyReceived" -> ((body = 
        ByteArrayToString@#[["BodyByteArray"]]) &)|>, 
 HandlerFunctionsKeys -> {"BodyByteArray"}]
```

Comment: It works because `ByteArrayToString` is "assuming it contains UTF-8 data", in general it could not be the case and decoding should be based on information in response's headers.